# The fastest way to check file exist in R or C for linux

Tags: c, linux, r

I am using file.exists to check whether files exist. However it will take longer time to check 4 millions files.

Is there faster to check file exists in R (or C codes)? I am using Linux platform.

Thanks for many suggestions.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: If you were  in R wouldn't you just use `system`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how to use system to check file exists.

Comment: The `file.exists` code probably uses either `stat()` or `access()` to check whether the file exists.  There isn't much you can do to speed that up other than access the files so that you deal with one directory at a time.  If all 4 million files are in a single directory, you have major problems; you need to break the single directory into multiple smaller directories (for 4 million files, at least 2 and perhaps 3 levels of sub-directory).

Comment: 4 million of anything is going to take a long time.

Comment: You just wrap the linux command line expression in `ret <- system("expression")`. I;m guessing there _must_ be an `ls` that would work. Not the R ls() but the Nix-`ls`.

Comment: @BondedDust: 4,000,000 `system` calls will take a godawfully long time.

Comment: @BondedDust: but if the 'expression' needs to generate 4 million files, you're going to run into 'argument list too big errors' rather quickly, aren't you?

Comment: @Bangyou: What format is this huge list of files in? And why do you need to see if all these files exist?

Comment: @nneonneo No. Not 4 MM calls .... one call to search 4 MM files.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your comments. I put 4 M files into 727 folders which only have about 6000 files in each folder. The other questions in Stackoverflow suggested stat() or access() are fastest ways to check files in linux. I will look at the source codes of file.exists() in R.

Comment: @nneonneo The files are text format, but I compressed them into *.RData. I am running some crop simulations with HTCondor (about 4M). Each simulation will generated a single file. I have to check whether all simulations are finished through checking the existence of outputs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just check the R source code. R do use stat() to check file in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Are you testing in a vectorized way, and if so what is a 'long time'?

```
>  n <- 1e7; fl <- rep(tempdir(), n); system.time(x <- file.exists(fl))
   user  system elapsed 
 10.887   3.712  14.601 
> table(x)
x
    TRUE 
10000000
```

If file.exists is very slow then perhaps you are accessing a network file system. Likely this is also a significant performance impediment to your simulations, and you should arrange for the simulations to take a more sane approach to data management.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am using the vectorized way. But my codes are much slower than yours. Will dig out for the bottleneck of my codes.

Comment: Yes I am using a network file system which in the same virtual machine. They should not have huge network delay. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.